# How to feed a table per timestamp to LSTM neural network?

Tags: neural-network, time-series, lstm, rnn

I have a time-series dataframe like this

```
         feat1  feat2  target
date id                      
0    1      12     16     192
     2      15      6      90
     3       2      9      18
1    1       0      3       0
     2       0      9       0
     3      56      9     504
2    1       5      9      45
     2       6      9      54
     3       5      8      40
```

and my problem is for regression.

What I know about the LSTM sequences, is that normally, the `row_id` is the date, so you build sequences of n rows.

In my data, as you can see, it's different. In each row that refers to the date, I have 3 more rows representing a product.

What I have thinked for make the sequence to my problem,  my `sequence` will be of 2 days:

```
sequence = [day0,day1],[day1,day2]
```

For every `date`, I have

```
date0 = [id1,id2,id3].
```

For every  `id`, I have:

```
id = [feat1,feat2].
```

the `sequence[0]`, and it would be something like

```
[
    [
        [12,16],
        [15,6],
        [2,9]
    ],[
        [0,3],
        [0.9],
        [56,9]
    ]
]
```

Is this valid?

Will the LSTM layer understand this? Or do I have to do some kind of extra transformation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data format is

```
                         feature1   feature2   target
             product1    1          12         2
 timestamp   product2    2          6          3
             product3    4          3          4
```

There are two designs for two assumptions:

1. Products are not related to each other. Therefore, each product could be modeled separately. That is, each timestamp is `X(t) = [feature1, feature2]` or, including the target, `X(t)|y(t) = [feature1, feature2, target]`. And we build a model for each product separately. In summary, LSTM receives two  1 x 3 sequences for `t-1` and `t`, and outputs a 1 x 1 target for `t + 1`. In notation:
   $$(\overbrace{X_{t-1}|y_{t-1}}^{1 \times 3}, \overbrace{X_{t}|y_{t}}^{1 \times 3}) \rightarrow \overbrace{y_{t+1}}^{1 \times 1}$$
2. Products are related to each other, meaning `product1` can help `product2` to predict its target. For this, we just need to flatten the 3 x 2 matrix to a 1 x 6 vector, where the order of values does not matter. That is,

   ```
   X(t) = [product1_feature1, product1_feature2, ..., product3_feature2]
   ```

   or

   ```
   X(t) = [product1_feature1, product2_feature1, ..., product3_feature2]
   ```

   We can also add the targets, for example

   ```
   X(t)|y(t) = [product1_feature1, product2_feature1, ..., product3_feature2, target1, ..., target3]
   ```

   This way, dimension of each timestamp would be 9 (6 + 3), and a sequence of two timestamps would be

   ```
   [
     [product1_feature1, product2_feature1, ..., product3_feature2, target1, ..., target3], # t-1
     [product1_feature1, product2_feature1, ..., product3_feature2, target1, ..., target3]  # t
   ]
   ```

   corresponding to a three dimensional target `[target1, ..., target3]` at `t + 1`.

   In summary, LSTM receives two 1 x 9 sequences for `t-1` and `t`, and outputs a 1 x 3 target for `t + 1`. In notation:
   $$(\overbrace{X_{t-1}|y_{t-1}}^{1 \times 9}, \overbrace{X_{t}|y_{t}}^{1 \times 9}) \rightarrow \overbrace{y_{t+1}}^{1 \times 3}$$

Comment: But I have 3 target on fact.

 [product1_feature1, product1_feature2,..., product3_feature2, target1,target2,target3]  # each t

Comment: @Extermis my bad! updated.